# Accessing Couchbase by terminal

Tags: database, couchbase, devops

Is it possible to create couchbase cluster by terminal. Basically, I want to perform all the operations on the DB by terminal.
Please refer me links, I have tried searching but could not find any terminal specific tutorial.
Suggest me if there is something I need to know before using Couchbase.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single tool for this, but the most comprehensive in terms of feature sets is the `cbc` command line.  There is [an older blog on the cbc tools](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-tools-shipped-couchbase-c-client-library-libcouchbase/), but the basic idea is you install the C SDK (a.k.a. libcouchbase) and you'll have man pages for cbc and cbc subcommands.

Another approach that is common is to use a Python shell with the Couchbase Python Client.  Or, use node.js with the Couchbase Node.js SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was trying it with cbq but the only thing I was able to do was querying, I wanted to have a full control like we have in mongodb.
I am trying cbc now, lets see how it works, will update once done.
Using python shell is a good approach for me, but for other people in team who are not familiar with python, its a bit difficult.

Comment: Just learned, there have been recent cbc updates too.  For example: http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-c-client-2.8.3/md_doc_cbc-subdoc.html

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.